# Random-Effects Model: Sigma u equals zero, Breusch-Pagan Lagrange Multiplier equals 1

Tags: multiple-regression, panel-data, random-effects-model, breusch-pagan

I have recently encountered a problem while running my Random-Effects Model. 
I am using an unbalanced panel data set which consists of time-invariant and time-variant variables. The time-invariant variables are cultural dimensions (GLOBE) and the time-variant variables are economic, population and infrastructure ones (GDP, Gini coefffient, foreign population etc.) My dependent variable is TTT_tot. My control variables are NE, _ios and _gp.

I have calculated three models with the following Stata code:

```
reg TTT_tot `eco_list' `cul_list' `infr_list' `pop_list' NE _ios _gp, vce(robust)
xtset CountryCode 
xtreg TTT_tot `eco_list' `cul_list' `infr_list' `pop_list' NE _ios _gp ,fe vce(robust)  
xtreg TTT_tot `eco_list' `cul_list' `infr_list' `pop_list' NE _ios _gp ,re vce(robust)
```

I want to compare a standard OLS regression, the Random-Effects Model and a Fixed-Effects model with one another, to be able to compare their standard errors and sigma u and sigma e values. However, I constantly receive a 0 for my sigma u value in my Random-Effects model.

```
Random-effects GLS regression                   Number of obs     =     11,934
Group variable: CountryCode                     Number of groups  =         19

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.0541                                         min =        594
     between = 1.0000                                         avg =      628.1
     overall = 0.1528                                         max =        630

                                                Wald chi2(13)     =          .
corr(u_i, X)   = 0 (assumed)                    Prob > chi2       =          .

                                             (Std. Err. adjusted for 19 clusters in CountryCode)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               |               Robust
                       TTT_tot |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                           GDP |   2.53e-06   4.09e-06     0.62   0.536    -5.48e-06    .0000105
                          Gini |  -.0559253   .5105896    -0.11   0.913    -1.056663    .9448119
           net_national_income |   -.001845   .0017765    -1.04   0.299     -.005327    .0016369
        UncertaintyAvoidanceSP |  -2.461559   .2853507    -8.63   0.000    -3.020836   -1.902281
           FutureOrientationSP |  -4.779695    .704769    -6.78   0.000    -6.161016   -3.398373
               PowerDistanceSP |  -5.717074   .2371044   -24.11   0.000     -6.18179   -5.252358
  CollectivismISPInstitutional |   17.74914     .52927    33.54   0.000     16.71179    18.78649
           HumaneOrientationSP |  -6.138548   .0818562   -74.99   0.000    -6.298983   -5.978113
      PerformanceOrientationSP |  -7.951868   .4913199   -16.18   0.000    -8.914837   -6.988899
    CollectivismIISPIngroupCol |  -1.273744   .7499475    -1.70   0.089    -2.743615    .1961257
        GenderEgalitarianismSP |   .5030384   .5760547     0.87   0.383    -.6260081    1.632085
               AssertivenessSP |   11.80073   .3703147    31.87   0.000     11.07492    12.52653
        UncertaintyAvoidanceSV |  -9.892615   .6663491   -14.85   0.000    -11.19864   -8.586595
           FutureOrientationSV |   1.941818   .2248855     8.63   0.000     1.501051    2.382586
               PowerDistanceSV |   11.56595   .7878502    14.68   0.000     10.02179    13.11011
  CollectivismISVInstitutional |   19.87028   .9030751    22.00   0.000     18.10028    21.64027
           HumaneOrientationSV |   8.966052    .961623     9.32   0.000     7.081306     10.8508
      PerformanceOrientationSV |  -2.439227    .112894   -21.61   0.000    -2.660495   -2.217959
    CollectivismIISVIngroupCol |   1.623323   .7085817     2.29   0.022     .2345288    3.012118
        GenderEgalitarianismSV |  -8.887995   .3053794   -29.10   0.000    -9.486528   -8.289462
               AssertivenessSV |   8.362968    .623689    13.41   0.000      7.14056    9.585376
        Broadband_subscription |   .0118887   .0081043     1.47   0.142    -.0039954    .0277728
mobile_broadband_subscriptions |  -.0003924   .0004245    -0.92   0.355    -.0012243    .0004396
                     urban_pop |   .5537966   1.768498     0.31   0.754    -2.912395    4.019988
              new_foreign_pop_ |   .2852685   .9709759     0.29   0.769    -1.617809    2.188346
        new_foreign_pop_growth |  -.0539973   .1212795    -0.45   0.656    -.2917008    .1837061
                  edu_post_sec |   2.001969   1.610598     1.24   0.214    -1.154745    5.158683
                      edu_tert |   .2519419   .7611614     0.33   0.741    -1.239907    1.743791
                            NE |  -6.031001   1.565617    -3.85   0.000    -9.099554   -2.962448
                          _ios |   .0218838   .0709499     0.31   0.758    -.1171756    .1609431
                           _gp |   .0341277   .0900629     0.38   0.705    -.1423923    .2106476
                         _cons |  -102.1462   12.21292    -8.36   0.000    -126.0831   -78.20936
-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                       sigma_u |          0
                       sigma_e |  12.622343
                           rho |          0   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here we can see the 0 value for `sigma_u`. Additionally, my between-estimator seems to be 1 (something I haven't found to be the case in other examples) and that one of my observational units (I have 20 countries in my sampel) has been omitted so that there are only 19 groups.

I have furthermore conducted a Breusch and Pagan Langrangian Multiplier test to determine whether I can even use a random-effects model. My Prob > chibar2 equals 1, which seems peculiar to me. (Especially since the RE model results in more statistically significant results, with better standard errors.)

If anyone would have any tips, or suggestions what I might be doing wrong, I'd be very grateful for any advice.